# Knex migration command result in error: Timeout acquiring a connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, knex.js

I'm building a backend project with Docker as my environment plus

- Node 17+
- Knex ^1.0.1
- PG ^8.7.1
- PostgreSQL 14.1-alpine

I was able to connect to my DB via a GUI as **Table Plus** and **DB Beaver**.
I also was able to use the `knex migrate:make` command to create the migration.

I followed some online and here suggestions to avoid this issue but I was unable to make it work.

Looks like I did a code mistake maybe.
No clue what's wrong right now.

Now the issue is with the command to migrate `knex migrate:latest` resulting as error

```sh
Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:307:26)
    at async Runner.ensureConnection (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:294:28)
    at async Runner.run (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:30:19)
    at async listCompleted (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/migration-list-resolver.js:12:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Migrator.latest (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/Migrator.js:63:29)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/jakub/Desktop/jakeDev/test/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js:232:32)
```

The way I configured Knex

```
const development = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: config.POSTGRES_HOST,
    database: config.POSTGRES_DB,
    user: config.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: config.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    createTimeoutMillis: 3000,
    acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    reapIntervalMillis: 1000,
    createRetryIntervalMillis: 100,
    propagateCreateError: false,
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: './src/database/migrations',
  },
};
```

And my migration setup

```
import tableNames from '../../constants/tableNames';
import { createTableName } from '../../utils/tableUtils.js';

/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
export async function up(knex) {
  await Promise.all([
    createTableName(knex, tableNames.pokemons),
    createTableName(knex, tableNames.restoredPokeDex),
  ]);
}

/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
export async function down(knex) {
  await Promise.all(
    [tableNames.pokemons, tableNames.restoredPokeDex].map((tableName) =>
      knex.schema.dropTableIfExists(tableName)
    )
  );
}
```

I'm importing the following part above

```
function tableDefaultColumns(table) {
  table.text('name').notNullable().unique();
  table.text('type_1').notNullable();
  table.text('type_2');
  table.integer('total').notNullable();
  table.integer('hp').notNullable();
  table.integer('attack').notNullable();
  table.integer('defense').notNullable();
  table.integer('sp_atk').notNullable();
  table.integer('sp_def').notNullable();
  table.integer('speed').notNullable();
  table.integer('generation').notNullable();
  table.boolean('legendary').defaultTo(false);
}

function createTableName(knex, tableName) {
  return knex.schema.createTableName(tableName, (table) => {
    table.increments().notNullable();
    tableDefaultColumns(table);
  });
}

export { tableDefaultColumns, createTableName };
```